# Accessing Tiered JSON data in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, twitch

I'm attempting to pull deeper values from JSON data at api.twitch.tv. I'm feeding the data to a MSGBOX for confirmation during testing, but the MSGBOX isn't even firing with a blank message, which I would expect at the very least. I've pushed the pre-parsed data to a textbox just fine, so I think it's having issues either in the parsing, or in my query.

JSON data being used:

```
{"follows":[{"created_at":"2015-07-12T04:13:40Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/budlight80/follows/channels/dubst3pgam3r"},"notifications":false,"user":{"_id":76860468,"name":"budlight80","created_at":"2014-12-09T01:16:00Z","updated_at":"2015-07-26T01:33:18Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/budlight80"},"display_name":"BudLight80","logo":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/budlight80-profile_image-57566d5de2333c49-300x300.jpeg","bio":"Just your basic guy....love great food, good beer, and great times with my friends.  ","type":"user"}}],"_total":211,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/dubst3pgam3r/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=0","next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/dubst3pgam3r/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=1"}}
```

VB.NET code being used:

```
    Dim jsonstring As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/dubst3pgam3r/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1")
    Dim Parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonstring)
    Dim Follower = Parsed("follows")("0")("user")("name")
    MsgBox(Follower)
```

Although the app is not halting or showing syntax issues, it is reporting "A first chance exception of type 'system.argumentexception' occured in newtonsoft.json.dll"

All I want to do is return a single drilled down value from the twitch api, never expected it to be like pulling teeth, lol.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You simply need a `ToString` on the end because you are selecting a `JToken` object and don't make the "0" argument a string - it should be an integer as it is an index to a collection.

```
Dim Follower = Parsed("follows")(0)("user")("name").ToString
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @joehanna. I did try this prior to posting the question, and revisited after your response, to no avail. I received the same exception mentioned above.

I tried adding .tostring to each of the 3 bottom lines individually, and also tried all 3 without ("0")

Comment: This isn't making much sense. The code I gave you with the data you provided works for me. Are you changing the code for the purpose of posting? Something else is missing.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, the .NET Framework, and JSON.NET are you using?

Comment: VB.NET 10.0.4
.NET Framework 4.5.51209SP1Rel
Json.NET 4.0 (File version 7.0.1.18622)

When I try to reference Json.NET 4.5 it tells
"Warning 1 The primary reference "Newtonsoft.Json" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client""

Publishing pre-req's offer 3.5 and 4.0, but not 4.5

Comment: Are you using Nuget to reference Newtonsoft?

Comment: Nope. Downloaded the libraries and manually added it to the references.

Comment: Then I would recommend removing those files and using Nuget to install the Newtonsoft library. You should get the correct version then. It will at least eliminate this as a possibility. There is no reason I can see otherwise why the code I gave you won't work.